# Unable to cut or copy VSCode popups

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, editor

I have been using VSCode for a long while now and am suddenly unable to cut or copy the VSCode popups that appear whenever you hover over something like a variable, class, function, module and especially errors.

[image]

This is a new issue which wasn't present earlier. Restarting VSCode or restarting the computer itself doesn't solve this issue. Is this an issue caused by changing keyboard shortcuts or cause of an extension??

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue because of the VSCode theme I was using and got fixed by just changing the theme. I was using the "Material Theme Darker" theme which makes the highlighting on error messages invisible. The text is still being highlighted, it's just that the highlighting is invisible making you look as if it isn't. Changing the theme fixes this issue.